# How to make a switch case with UTF8 string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, switch-statement

I have this function who work all the time but just for the "µ" possibility, it does not work:

```js
function obtenirFacteur(multiple){
    var facteur = 1;
    switch(multiple){
        case "T" :
            facteur = 1000000000000;
            break;
        case "G" :
            facteur = 1000000000;
        case "M" :
            facteur = 1000000;
            break;
        case "K" :
            facteur = 1000;
            break;
        case "h" :
            facteur = 100;
            break;
        case "da" :
            facteur = 10;
            break;
        case "d" :
            facteur = 0.1;
            break;
        case "c" :
            facteur = 0.01;
            break;
        case "m" :
            facteur = 0.001;
            break;
        case "μ":
            facteur = 0.000001;
            break;
        case "n" :
            facteur = 0.000000001;
            break;
        case "p" :
            facteur = 0.000000000001;
            break;
        case "f" :
            facteur = 0.000000000000001;
            break;
    }
    return facteur;
}
```

But it does not work for the string "µ".

My file is in UTF8 without BOM in notepad++, what usually work for all the situation.

Comment: File saving is the issue. It doesn't have any problem if you paste it in Chrome's Developer Tools Console and then try to test the function - it works as expected.

Comment: How are you calling the function? Where does the caller get the argument value from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mu = "µ"
console.log("µ".localeCompare(mu, "pl");)
```

Should be fine

Comment: the best way to check the navigator it seems.

Answer (score 0):

> My file is in UTF8 without BOM in notepad++,

check after entering the letter whether it remain as such, I guess it changes after pasting it
you can try also with accented letters like `á` and check whether the file is still UTF-8 without BOM, if it is not, change it back to it, and fix the letter if it turned into something else, from that point it will be ok

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce your problem in REPL of Node

```
$ node --version
v8.9.4
$ node
> function test(m) {
... switch(m) {
..... case "μ": return 100; break;
..... default: return 0; break;
..... }
... }
undefined
> test('a')
0
> test('μ')
100
>
```

Works even with `LC_ALL=C`

PS: I know this is not an answer, but SO doesn't let me comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

> The data you are reading from file is encoded, you have to decode it.

Use the following

```
switch(decodeURIComponent(multiple))
```

e.g.

```js
let decodedData = decodeURIComponent(`%c2%b5`)
console.log('decodedData : ', decodedData)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is really not the  best, but i should go ahead, so :

```js
function obtenirFacteur(multiple){
    var facteur = 1;
    if(multiple)="µ"){
      multiple = mu;
    }
    switch(multiple){
        case "T" :
            facteur = 1000000000000;
            break;
        case "G" :
            facteur = 1000000000;
        case "M" :
            facteur = 1000000;
            break;
        case "K" :
            facteur = 1000;
            break;
        case "h" :
            facteur = 100;
            break;
        case "da" :
            facteur = 10;
            break;
        case "d" :
            facteur = 0.1;
            break;
        case "c" :
            facteur = 0.01;
            break;
        case "m" :
            facteur = 0.001;
            break;
        case "mu":
            facteur = 0.000001;
            break;
        case "n" :
            facteur = 0.000000001;
            break;
        case "p" :
            facteur = 0.000000000001;
            break;
        case "f" :
            facteur = 0.000000000000001;
            break;
    }
    return facteur;
}
```

When it works for some of you, it es probably just a behaviour for a navigator, not a programmation problem.
Thanks for your help !